# How to count the number of perfect square greater than $N$ and less than $N^2$ that are relatively prime to $N$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, totient-function, square-numbers

I know a little about Euler's totient function that counts integer less than $N$ that are relatively prime to $N$.

But I don't know how to modify the function for perfect square numbers, or maybe there is another formula I don't know about.

Can somebody provide any help? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may assume that 
$$ N=\prod_{l=1}^{k} p_l^{\alpha_l} $$
is the factorization of $N$ and define $\square_N(m)$ as the number of squares $\leq m$ that are coprime with $N$. For our purposes it is enough to compute $\square_N(N^2)-\square_N(N)$, where $\square_N(m)$ accounts for the integers in the range $[1,\sqrt{m}]$ that are coprime with $p_1,p_2,\ldots,p_k$. By the inclusion-exclusion principle $\square_N(m)$ is expected to behave like
$$\sqrt{m}\prod_{l=1}^{k}\left(1-\frac{1}{p_l}\right)$$
plus a small error term, hence $\square_N(N^2)-\square_N(N)$ is expected to behave like
$$ N\prod_{l=1}^{k}\left(1-\frac{1}{p_l}\right) +O(\sqrt{N}) = \varphi(N)+O(\sqrt{N}).$$

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer ,,

But I am just a beginner and i can't understand your formula well..
can you explain it in general language please?

Comment: this is the problem statement sir..
given a number N, you should count how many perfect square numbers bigger than N and smaller than N^2, which has no prime factor exists in number N factorization (i.e. all of the prime factors do not exist in number N factorization)

if N = 10 then the output should 2 (49 & 81)
if N = 12 then the output should 3

thanks